# How to update status in Admin from a drop downlist

Tags: django, django-admin

Hi I have in my order Model a status where I can choose the status of the order.

I want to be able to update the status from the external display of the admin instead of going inside of the detail view of the order.

Here is the models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                              choices=[('pending', 'Pending'), ('ofd', 'Out For Delivery'), ('recieved', 'Recieved')],
                              default='pending')
```

Here is the admin.py

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'ordered', 'ordered_date', 'status','ref_code']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to be able to update the status from the list page, you can set [`list_editable`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) on your admin class

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_editable = ['status']
    ...
```